# Locally compact connected topological group is paracompact

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

> Let $G$ be a locally compact, connected topological group. Show that $G$ is a paracompact.

I was trying to prove it with defining $U_n$ by defining

$U_1$ to be a symmetric neighborhood of $e$ having compact closure, and $U_{n+1} =\bar U_n \circ U_1$.

Now I have only step to show $U=\cup U_n$ is subgroup of $G$. However, I was stuck to show

> For each $a\in U$, $a^{-1} \in U$

Comment: Try to show $G$ is $\sigma$-compact and hence Lindelöf regular, so strongly paracompact.

Comment: I can finish the proof if I suppose $U$ is subgroup of $G$. However, I am struggling to prove the assumption...

Comment: Note that $U_1$ is symmetrical, so $a \in U_1$ implies $-a \in U_1$. Closures preserve this property. Products too... Open subgroups are closed too. The only oopen-and-closed non-empty set in a connected $G$ equals $G$..

Comment: Oh Thanks a lot!